# Can FluentValidation be used/combined with the railway style pattern of programming?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, fluentvalidation

I've been using FluentValidation for a quite a while and it serves its use quite well.

I am currently converting a project from `.Net 4.8` to `.Net Core 6.0`, and I also updated the code to work with the latest version of FluentValidation (11) from a much earlier version (7).

Lately, more and more, I come across situations where I need to validate data and produce a version of that data that is valid. This need also arises from the `c#` compiler support for null-state static analysis and non-nullable references.

An example:

Let's say I have a web form where the user uploads an attachment and she/he also specifies the attachment category from a dropdown.

In the controller I can use this class to store the form data:

```cs
public class FormData {
  public IFormFile? FormFile {get; set;}
  public int? CategoryId {get; set;}
}
```

The validation takes this input, it validates it and at the end it could produce class like this one (as a minimum):

```cs
public class FormDataValidated {
  public IFormFile FormFile {get; set;}
  public int CategoryId {get; set;}
}
```

Note that the fields become in the validated version non-nullable.

Can FluentValidation be used, in addition to validate the data in an object, to create a transformed object with the valid data? This sort of pattern comes from the [functional programming world](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/).

Essentially, validation becomes a function that takes an input, it takes the validation rules and it returns either a validated input or a list of issues/problems identified in the input.

FluentValidation seems to support very well the validation rules and validation itself, but it doesn't seem to allow one to assemble the validated data back into another object, unless I am missing something. That's my question, is it possible with FluentValidation to assemble the validated data back into a new type of object?

Thanks

Comment: a mapper library might be the best thing

Comment: No, FluentValidation's purpose is only to validate your data. You are looking for a mapper to perform the data mapping/transformation. Otherwise, you need to implement your own to validate data and data transform. However in my opinion, this will violate the Single Responsibility (S) rule in SOLID principle.

Comment: I started to look at different functional libraries for C# - I found a sample to show what I am looking for: https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/blob/bce0a161f8d07b0946b95c451daaeee8c732ee2a/LanguageExt.Tests/ValidationTests.cs#L257

Comment: Basically, as you validate the data, you also collect the validated pieces and possibly transform them (ex. convert a string to int, or convert a string to date), then you build the final validated object.

Comment: I don't think I can achieve this type of processing with FluentValidation. I read again the documentation, and I found this: https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/advanced.html#root-context-data, but I think this is more for passing data to the validator, rather than collecting validated pieces.

Comment: What bothered me in the past with FluentValidation is occasional duplication of certain operations. If I need to make sure a string contains a number, I would have to parse that string, but then when you need to grab the number and save it somewhere later, you need to do the parsing again knowing this time that it will be successful. Because my application is not heavily used, I didn't care about this duplication.

Comment: @DanielA.White I use AutoMapper. I feel ambivalent about AutoMapper. Yes, this might work, however, read my comments above. By the time I run the mapper to copy the data from one object to another, I know that the transformation is going to work but this knowledge is not obvious, it is not reflected in the types that I am manipulating. You'd always have to read the validation code to make sure you validated everything.

Comment: This is rather a question of "should you" than "could you". While FV itself does not support this, you could of course write a wrapper that combines validation and mapping. But keeping those two separate concerns separate also bears its advantages. You can map to different types after validation if needed. You can _unit test_ validators and mappers separately. etc. Generally, your alarm bells should be ringing if something in your codebase does one thing _and_ something else. Most of the time, it should stop in front of the "and".

Comment: But nothing would stop you from _chaining_ validation and mapping subsystems. I just see it making things more complicated if things go south ( dto is *in*valid, mapping fails ... ) ?

Comment: _" You'd always have to read the validation code to make sure you validated everything."_ - that's what unit tests are for. FluentValidation has **excellent** testing support. And unit testing mappers saved my behind more than once ...